# Setting up email on a Ubuntu VPS

Tags: ubuntu, email, vps

I am using a 123-reg VPS with Ubuntu. The web sites are working fine as is mySql Database, mail is another issue.
I get the following error when sending a email to the new server via outlook:
retry time not reached for any host after a long failure period

And through Thunderbird:
An error occurred while sending mail. The mail server responded:  Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable or not local. Please check the message recipient kev@mydomain.com and try again.

The setup is thus..

VPS is at 212.xx.xx.xx7
Domain name is mydomain.com

My settings at Joker.com

```
A Records
Host            Target          TTL
mydomain.com        212.xx.xx.xx7       7200
www.mydomain.com        212.xx.xx.xx7       8200
mx.mydomian.com     212.xx.xx.xx7       1800
ldap.mydomian.com       212.xx.xx.xx7       1800
mail.mydomian.com       212.xx.xx.xx7       1800

MX-Records                      Priority
Mydomain.com        mail.mydomain.com   10
```

On VPS I used this step thru guide (http://www.pixelinx.com/2013/09/creating-a-mail-server-on-ubuntu-postfix-courier-ssltls-spamassassin-clamav-amavis/) setting mail.example.com to match above.

dig mx mydomain.com returns

```
mydomain.com 86400 IN MX 10 mail. mydomain.com
mail. mydomain.com 86400 IN A 212.xx.xx.xx7
```

authtest kev@ mydomain.com returns

```
Authenticated: kev@mydomain.com (uid 5000, gid 5000)
```

Etc etc, all looks correct

So, can anyone see where I am going wrong please?

Comment: Jenny, thanks for the tidy up. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telnet to your server on Port 25 `telnet 212.xx.xx.xx7 25` if connected, type `ehlo` to see if the server is responsive as it should.

- Have you tried restarting the mail service on the server?
- Did you confirm that the mail address is typed correctly?
- Can you confirm that the user is already created on the mail server?